# Graph API get facebook Youtube links from my facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get my youtube links from my wall. I have generated an account key but when I try to get data it is empty. Im using

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname

Comment: Do you have any sample code we can look at? -  otherwise this will get closed.

Comment: I dont have any example, Im just trying to get data from here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible via the Graph API, but feasible with a FQL query like this one:

```
select link_id, url from link where owner=me() and strpos(lower(url), 'youtube') >= 0
```

You can call this via Graph Explorer like this

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20link_id%2C%20url%20from%20link%20where%20owner%3Dme()%20and%20strpos(lower(url)%2C%20%27youtube%27)%20%3E%3D%200](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20link_id%2C%20url%20from%20link%20where%20owner%3Dme%28%29%20and%20strpos%28lower%28url%29%2C%20%27youtube%27%29%20%3E%3D%200)

or via a browser window like this

[https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20link_id%2C%20url%20from%20link%20where%20owner%3Dme()%20and%20strpos(lower(url)%2C%20%27youtube%27)%20%3D%200&access_token=](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20link_id%2C%20url%20from%20link%20where%20owner%3Dme%28%29%20and%20strpos%28lower%28url%29%2C%20%27youtube%27%29%20%3D%200&access_token=){your_access_token}

Replace {your_access_token} with an Access Token with `read_stream` permission!